# Users authenticating via AD are no longer being prompted for password

Tags: login, active-directory

Platforms: Oracle Linux 5, Oracle Linux 6
PowerbrokerOpen V7.01

What we want to happen: Users are able to login to the Linux command line using their Active Directory username and password.

What's happening now: Users are logging in with their AD login, and are no longer being prompted for a password

What changed:  The Linux machines were migrated from the domain "MYCOMPANY.NET" to "MYCOMPANY.LOCAL" as the "MYCOMPANY.NET domain will be removed.

This is output in /var/log/secure from a machine that has not migrated yet:

```
Feb 11 14:51:07 prdsrv101 sshd[32690]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for davthac  from 10.53.25.44 port 53561 ssh2
Feb 11 14:51:07 prdsrv01 sshd[32690]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user davthac by (uid=0)
```

This is output in /var/log/secure from a machine that has been migrated:

```
Feb 11 14:57:00 tstivxapp01 sshd[10161]: Authorized to davthac, krb5 principal davthac@MYCOMPANY.LOCAL (krb5_kuserok)
Feb 11 14:57:00 tstivxapp01 sshd[10161]: Accepted gssapi-with-mic for davthac from 10.53.25.44 port 53777 ssh2
Feb 11 14:57:00 tstivxapp01 sshd[10161]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user davthac by (uid=0)
```

It looks like the authentication method was changed, but we made no configuration changes to Powerbroker other than leaving MYCOMPANY.NET and joining MYCOMPANY.LOCAL.

What do I need to do to get the password prompt back?

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: Not sure enough to write an Answer, but it looks like your Linux systems are now using SSO. In `/etc/sshd_config` try setting `UsePAM yes`, `PasswordAuthentication yes`, `GSSAPIAuthentication no`, and `KerberosAuthentication yes` (although possibly `no`) and restarting sshd. DO NOT LOG OUT OF YOUR ROOT SHELL until you know you can log back in again!

Answer (score 0):

Had to disable `GSSAPIAuthentication` in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`file. This worked for me too as shown below.

```
 $cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep GSSA
# Ciphers, MACs, KexAlgoritms and GSSAPIKexAlgorithsm will not have any
# GSSAPI options
*GSSAPIAuthentication no*
```